# Javascript: put values from arrays together

Tags: javascript, arrays, analytics

I have an array with countries and an array with cities + countries.

Array 1 (countries) and how it's made:

```
query({
  'ids': ids,
  'dimensions': 'ga:country',
  'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
  'sort': '-ga:sessions',
  'start-date': moment(now).subtract('days', 730).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
  'end-date': moment(now).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
})
.then(function(response) {

  var countries = [];
  response.rows.forEach(function(row, i) {
    countries.push({ value: +row[0]+': '+row[1], color: 'white', country: row[0], text: row[0]+': '+row[1]});
//text = country and visits
  }); 
});
```

Array 2 (cities):

```
query({
    'ids': ids,
    'dimensions': 'ga:city, ga:country',
    'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
    'sort': '-ga:sessions',
    'start-date': moment(now).subtract('days', 730).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    'end-date': moment(now).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    var cities = [];
    response.rows.forEach(function(row, i) {
      cities.push({ value: +row[1]+': '+row[0], color: 'white', label: row[0]+': '+row[2]});
//label = city and visits
//value = country and city
    });
  });
```

I want this:

COUNTRY1 - 245

- City1 - 105
- City2 - 140

COUNTRY2 - 1180

- City5 - 530
- City8 - 650

I don't know where to start from here. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need an array within an object, e.g.:

```
{
    "country-1": ["city-1", "city-2"],
    "country-2": ["city-3", "city-4"]
}
```

Comment: Exactly. But those two arrays I described in the post are from Google Analytics, so I can't change them.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand. You don't need to change them, you just need to push them into your object.

Comment: You mean I have to make objects from the countries, and then push the cities in the countries where countries do match?